# Using Spring Boot without the parent POM

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I'm trying to merge two Maven projects into one while both of them have `<parent>` section. Since one of them is a Spring-Boot project, according to [this documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-maven-without-a-parent), I should be able to include the necessary dependencies for Spring-Boot into my project by an import:

```
<dependencyManagement>
     <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

But when I remove the parent section of the Maven project and add the above tag to my `<dependencyManagement>`, the code does not compile anymore with the following error message:

```
Error:(5, 45) java: package org.springframework.boot.test.context does not exist
```

Can someone please tell me how to switch from `<parent>` to `<dependencyManagement>`?

Comment: Please create the one maven module  for the spring boot dependencies then import to original maven (Pom.xml) . But one thing without parent spring boot maven dependencies you can't execute spring boot .

Comment: That error would happen if you had an older version of `spring-boot-test` on the classpath. Perhaps something in the parent is overriding the import you've shown above? What does the output from `mvn dependency:tree` look like?

Comment: @LovaChittumuri That's incorrect. You just need to configure Spring Boot's Maven plugin manually rather than inheriting configuration from the parent